# How trigger a pipeline Job if any of a matrix job succeeded in Gitlab CI Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hi I try to realize the following:

I have a matrix job where potentially only a part of the matrix job is executed. Therefore I want to trigger a following job every time any of the matrix jobs is passed/failed.

can this be realized somehow by the `rules` keyword?

Usually the `needs` keyword would fit but this depends on **all** matrix jobs.

Is the same possible for a set of jobs where a following job shall be executed each time any of the jobs in the set are passed/failed?